# PHP form post saving New line Character in MySQL is inconsistent in different platforms like Android/IOS

Tags: php, android, ios, mysql, user-input

I have an app that uses Android and iOS platforms with a PHP-based Backend written in REST.

I have a strange problem, where some users(not all only some of them) who are on mobile platforms like Android and iOS when they post data and saved to the MySQL DB,

**I see that it converts newline character to \r\n. like the below example.**

[image]

**While some other users just invisible new line charactors but correctly displayed the newline character in the output.**

[image]

In my coding it just simple MVC save from the form post,

```
        $text = new UsersText();
        $text->headline = $param->headline;
        $text->essay = $param->essay;
        $text->date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());
        $text->save();
```

**MySQL DB field is set to charactor encording "utf8_general_ci"** and Website app outputs UTF-8, I doubts they are an issue since its happens only to subset of users, I wonder

1. Why is this happening to some set of users?
2. What is the best approach to make the input universal?

Any help and guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `I see that it converts newline character to \r\n. like the below example.` Sorry, but i see nothing.

Comment: @blackapps yes that is the issue. Sometimes it converts to \r\n sometimes its invisible.

Comment: Nothing will be converted to \r\n to begin with. But do you take into account that if Android/Linux sends a text with newlines that the newlines are "\n". If Windows does it the newlines are "\r\n" and if iOs does it that the newlines are  "\r" ? Does your backend and following code take that in account?

Comment: No i don't fo any modifications to the input. If i need to let me know. My question is why its converts to\r\n in the first place? How do I have a universal input for newlines? If i need to do modifications what are they?

Comment: `My question is why its converts to\r\n ` Who is telling you that that happens? As stated before: i do not see that. It is not visible in the images. If i cannot see it then how can you? Further you still did not tell WHAT is converted to \r\n.

Comment: @blackapps first screenshot last charactor is "\r\n" is a new line, in the second screenshot you see its line breaks that works on windows...etc why? same post data, two different save in the MySQL. definitely user is not going enter "\r\n" into the text, must be added by the system they using...